# Connecting and Authorizing with the Google APIs Java Client

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I get confused with the guild [Connecting and Authorizing with the Google APIs Java Client](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_with_the_google_apis_java_client)

I have written the following code and get the service instance

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
```

I don't know what the next step is.

It seem to me that the Drive class in this code is different class from Drive in [Google API for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Drive)

Then should I follow the Drive REST API or Drive API for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are 2 different APIs, and it is not recommended to mix them together. The REST Api ([v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk) and [v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk)) use

```
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mGOOSvc =
  new Drive.Builder(
    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
    new GsonFactory(),
    GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(Context, Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
   ....
  )
.build();
```

to access GooDrive services, i.e. you call the methods like:

```
mGOOSvc.files().get()...
mGOOSvc.files().list()....
mGOOSvc.files().insert()...
mGOOSvc.files().patch()...
mGOOSvc.files().update()...
mGOOSvc.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest()...
```

using this service that you instantiated.

On the other hand, [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) uses a different construct:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient mGAC 
  = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Context)
  .addApi(Drive.API)
  .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
  .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
  .addConnectionCallbacks( new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {...})
  .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {...})
  ....
  .build();
```

to create `GoogleApiClient mGAC` used to access GDAA like so:

```
mGAC.connect() / disconnect()
Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGAC)...
Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGAC)...
Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGAC, ...)...
Drive.DriveApi.query(mGAC, ...)...
DriveFolder.createFile(mGAC, ..., ...)
...
```

As I mentioned above, DO NOT MIX the two APIs unless you know what the implications are (GDAA is a local service - see `Drive Local Context` in `Lifecycle of a Drive file` [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files), the REST Api talks directly to the network).

There are 2 examples of these two APIs available on GitHub, solving the same problem (building and reading a directory tree) here ([REST](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo)) and here ([GDAA](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo)). The `MainActivity` of these two is pretty much the same, and it calls methods of wrapper classes REST or GDAA respectively.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank a lot for your explanation.

Comment: If you decide to play with the Github samples, you can safely strip the Accounr Manager (UT.AM), Account Picker and 'email' stuff to simplify it. The account selection will be handled by the services. Your app just will not know whose account your user selected.